# Flex in Android , What is the difference between these codes?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, mxml, flex4.5

```
source="assets/Check.png"
```

and

```
source="@Embed(source='assets/Check.png')"
```

I want to know is there any differences in these?
I can't see any difference in these through my project.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first syntax loads image at runtime. The second one embed image into binary.